# get large picture from facebook page

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, request

I spent the last 5 hours trying to get large picture from Facebook page using this request:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/Y.Anti.coup.D?fields=name,picture?type=large&access_token=CAAHH9uJXXOcBA

But I always get this error:

> {    "error": {
>         "message": "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"?\".\" at character 12: name,picture?type=large",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 2500    } }

Sorry for my bad English, and I hope that you understand my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a lot easier:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/picture?type=large
```

(no Access Token needed btw)

In your case, the problem is that you are using the question mark two times. This is how your code should work:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/Y.Anti.coup.D?fields=name,picture&type=large&access_token=CAAHH9uJXXOcBA
```